# Coldfusion tabs create javascript style width

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, tabs, coldfusion-10

New at coldfusion here. I am needing to change the width of a tab area. This is the following code that I currently have:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var x = screen.width - 100;

       console.log(x);
       $("[name=theTabs]").css({'width':x + 'px'});
   });
</script>
<cflayout name="theTabs" type="tab" style="width: 10px;">
```

Once the page loads up, the width of the tab area is still 10px....

What could I be doing incorrect?

Comment: Obligatory note/"nag" that you should really stay away from ColdFusion's markup tags and create the HTML/CSS yourself. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches down the road. Here's an [example for cflayout-tab](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/cflayout-tabs/index.md).

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 elemets that need to be resized.

I don't know 100% if it matters, but you may want to put the script after the cflayout just to make sure it rendered in the page before trying to run js against it.

```
<cflayout name="theTabs" type="tab" style="width: 10px;"></cflayout>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = screen.width - 100;
        console.log(x);
        $("#theTabs").css({'width':x +'px'});
        $(".x-tab-panel").css({'width':x +'px'});
        $(".x-tab-panel-header").css({'width':(x-2) +'px'});
        $(".x-tab-panel-body").css({'width':(x-2) +'px'});
   });
</script>
```